# Show formatted properties in Laravel's blade template

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, architecture, yii2

Let's say, I have some `Model` with `updated_at` attribute. I want to show it in template like this

```
{{ $model->updated_at }}
```

This can be used in many places so I DO NOT do this

```
{{ $model->updated_at->format('d/m/Y H:i:s') }}
```

But instead

```
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
}
```

But there is one big problem with this solution, I can not use `$model->updated_at` in controllers anymore, because it returns string, not Carbon instance.

Two possible solutions

1.

```
public function getUpdatedAtFormatterAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->updated_at->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
}
```

and in template

```
{{ $model->updated_at_formatted }}
```

2.

Use package like [this](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter)

```
class ModelPresenter extends Presenter {

    public function updated_at()
    {
        return $this->updated_at->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
    }
}
```

And

```
{{ $model->present()->updated_at }}
```

From architectural point view I think second version is cleaner but are there some proven solutions? This can be not about Laravel only but about any popular PHP framework.

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem. I would like to discuss it with you... Do you have facebook or something so we can chat? I have made a solution for this I think, but want to hear from you if it works for you also.

Comment: this question s for Yii2 or laravel ?

Comment: More for Laravel, but I think the problem exists also in Yii2

Comment: I use your first approach unless the application is really big, where I usually have a repository interface and when needed I implement a "presenter"/"transformer" on top of the repository.

Comment: @devk I would like to see that "presenter"/"transformer" do you have facebook or something?

Comment: @lewis4u [Here's](https://github.com/d1am0nd/wp/blob/master/app/Repositories/Transformers/CardRepository.php) an example. It extends [CardRepository](https://github.com/d1am0nd/wp/blob/master/app/Repositories/CardRepository.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods described in the question are, in fact, *the* standard and widely-accepted approaches to adding DRY date-formatting on Laravel models:

- Add one or more accessors to a model for specific date formats
- Use a *presenter* that wraps the model with logic for display

Both approaches consolidate the formatting logic at one location so we can update the format later, if needed, without changing every line that outputs a date. Both also avoid overriding the source attribute so the functionality is available when needed.

Which to choose depends on the size and requirements of the application. Smaller applications with small teams can certainly justify the first approach, which avoids introducing complexity by adding a presenter layer. The second approach may suit larger teams that can benefit from the abstraction and seperation-of-concerns.

In some applications, I like to make a trait that we can add to any model which enables automatic date formatting attributes using the dates and date format declared on the model:

```
class User extends Model 
{
    use FormatsDates; 

    protected $dates = [ 'last_login_at' ]; 
    ...
}

$user->formatted_last_login_at; // mm/dd/yyyy
```

Because this question doesn't include such a trait in its scope, I'll leave the implementation as an exercise to the reader, but I'm happy to help if needed.

Comment: why can't I save a date in this format "d.m.Y H:i" even if I add it to the $dates[ ] array in model?

Comment: @lewis4u, there are several factors to consider when saving dates in a different format. If the database column stores the format as `d.m.Y H:i`, then you can set the `$dateFormat` property on the model to the some. Otherwise, you'll need to convert the date first: `$model->some_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i', $someDate); $model->save();`. You may consider adding a mutator for this attribute to the model for a specific date format.

Comment: What if I want to have a universal mutator for any model like a Trait...I have already created one but would like to discuss it with yo, to see it and say your opinion...

Comment: @lewis4u Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155856/laravel-formatsdates-trait).

Answer (score 0):

try this - don't forget call in model- use Carbon\Carbon;
Model:

```
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($updated_at)
{
    return Carbon::parse($updated_at)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
}
```

In your blade view call like this

```
{{$model->getUpdatedAtAttribute($updated_at)}}
```

Comment: Did you try that?